# Vertx worker verticle pool for jdbc

Tags: jdbc, vert.x

I'm new to Vert.x and I would like to implement a pool of worker verticles to make database queries using BoneCP. However, I'm a little bit confused about how to 'call' them to work and how to share the BoneCP connection pool between them.

I saw in Vertx DeploymentManager [source](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/3.3.3/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/impl/DeploymentManager.java#L434) that the `start(Future)` method is called synchronously and then the verticle is kept in memory until undeployed. After the `start` method completes, what's the correct way of calling methods on the worker verticle? If I deploy many instances of the verticle (using `DeploymentOptions.setInstances()`), will Vertx do load balancing between them?

I saw that Vert.x comes with a JDBC client and a worker pool, but it has limited datatypes I can work with because it uses the EventBus and serializes all data returned by the database. I need to work with many different datatypes (including dates, BigDecimals and binary objects) and I would like to avoid serialization as much as possible, but instead make queries in the worker verticle, process the results and return an object via a Future or AsyncResult (I believe this is done on-heap, so no serialization needed; is this correct?).

Please help me to sort out all these questions :) I will appreciate a lot if you give me examples of how can I make this work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer your questions one by one.

> how to 'call' them to work

You call your worker verticles using the EventBus. That's the proper way to communicate between them. Please see this example:
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/verticle/worker/MainVerticle.java#L27

> how to share the BoneCP connection pool between them.

Don't. Instead, create a small connection pool for each. Otherwise, it will cause unexpected behavior.

```
config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(1);
config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(5);
config.setPartitionCount(1);
```

> will Vertx do load balancing between them

No. That's the reason @Jochen Bedersdorfer and I suggest to use EventBus. You can have a reference to your worker verticle, as you suggested, but then you're stuck with 1:1 configuration.

> return an object via a Future or AsyncResult (I believe this is done
>   on-heap, so no serialization needed; is this correct?)

This is correct. But again, you're stuck with 1:1 mapping then. Which is a lot worse in terms of performance that serialization (that's using buffers).

If you still do need something like that, maybe you shouldn't use worker verticles at all, but something like `.executeBlocking`:
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/execblocking/ExecBlockingExample.java#L25

Answer (score 0):

In your `start(...)` method, register event listeners with event bus as this is how you interact with verticles (worker or not).
Yes, if you deploy many instances, Vert.x will use round-robin to send messages to those instances.

For what you describe, Vert.x might not be the best fit, since it works best with asynchronous I/O.
You might be better off using standard Java concurrency tools to manage the load, i.e. Executor and friends.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll setup my verticles with listeners on the event bus in order to process requests, but I still have to work on how to share the jdbc connection pool between them. I wanted to implement this in Vert.x to learn the framework and take advantage of async I/O to process lots of requests with fewer resources :)